# php show login status message does not update

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to display a status message when someone tries to log in. The issue I'm having is:

- after I check login, and it doesn't match, it outputs `$loginStatusMessage == "doesn't match"`, but not within the HTML (which I would like, since it's wrapped in CSS styling tags).
- Instead, the HTML `$loginStatusMessage` echos "welcome" even after the variable is updated.

I'm guessing this is because after the form calls itself to run the PHP, it reloads the $loginStatusMessage with welcome? How can I make it so that the HTML `$loginStatusMessage` changes to `doesn't match` when I submit the form?

I have global var `$loginStatusMessage`

```
$loginStatusMessage = "welcome";

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    Login($username, $password);
}

function Login($username, $password)
{       
    if(!checkLogin($username, $password))
    {
        $loginStatusMessage = "doesn't match...";
        echo $loginStatusMessage; 
    }
    else { 
        session_start();
```

**This echo outputs:** `"doesn't match"`, but not within the HTML in the body

---

But in my body, I have:

```
<p class='loginMsg'><?php echo $loginStatusMessage; ?></p>
```

**This echo outputs:** `"welcome"`

So when I submit the form, I call the same file:

```
<form id='register' action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the variable

```
   $loginStatusMessage;
```

And then in your code if the validation "matches" then

```
   $loginStatusMessage="Welcome";
```

if Not

```
   $loginStatusMessage="Doesn't match";
```

Now in the part you have to print the variable do this:

```
   <p class='loginMsg'><?php 

    if($loginStatusMessage!=null){
    echo $loginStatusMessage; 
    }

    ?></p>
```

Hope it helped

Comment: This did not fix the issue. It now displays no message

Answer (score 0):

I did some experimenting in my notepad++ and xampp i think this will do for you

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    Login($username, $password);
}

function Login($username, $password)
{       
    if(!checkLogin($username, $password))
    {
        $loginStatusMessage .= "doesn't match...";
        echo $loginStatusMessage; 
    }
    else { 
        $loginStatusMessage .= "welcome";
        echo  $loginStatusMessage;
        session_start();
```